# Java SimpleDateFormat shifts Date by one year

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, type-conversion

I'm getting very weird results, which I can not understand.

```
public class Test {

  private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d = new Date(1356912000000L);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
  }  
}
```

Gives the output:

```
Mon Dec 31 01:00:00 CET 2012
31.12.2013 01:00
```

I assume that this might be some issues with locales, but that's a shift by a whole year ! May anyone explain why it performs this way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`YYYY` is the week-year, not the calendar year. You want `yyyy` instead. Here's Java's relevant details:

### [Week Of Year and Week Year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year)

> Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR field range from 1 to 53. The
> first week of a calendar year is the earliest seven day period
> starting on getFirstDayOfWeek() that contains at least
> getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days from that year. It thus depends on
> the values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), getFirstDayOfWeek(), and
> the day of the week of January 1. Weeks between week 1 of one year and
> week 1 of the following year (exclusive) are numbered sequentially
> from 2 to 52 or 53 (except for year(s) involved in the
> Julian-Gregorian transition).
>
> The getFirstDayOfWeek() and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() values are
> initialized using locale-dependent resources when constructing a
> GregorianCalendar. The week determination is compatible with the ISO
> 8601 standard when getFirstDayOfWeek() is MONDAY and
> getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4, which values are used in locales
> where the standard is preferred. These values can explicitly be set by
> calling setFirstDayOfWeek() and setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek().
>
> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
> the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
> Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different
> calendar year values.
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
> MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
> compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997,
> and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
> days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
> SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
> January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
> 53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

`"dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm"`

Use:

`"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"`